# Type errors when installing ng-maps: Property is incompatible with index signature

Tags: angular, typescript, dependencies

I'm trying to install @ng-maps/core into an Angular 15 project. As soon as I import `NgMapsCoreModule` into app.module.ts and try to run the app, I get a ton of type errors that all look similar to this:

```
Error: node_modules/@ng-maps/core/lib/directives/circle.d.ts:141:88 - error TS2344: Type '{ 
latitude: { alias: "latitude"; required: false; }; longitude: { alias: "longitude"; required:
false; }; clickable: { alias: "clickable"; required: false; }; draggable: { alias: 
"draggable"; required: false; }; ... 8 more ...; zIndex: { ...; }; }' does not satisfy 
the constraint '{ [key: string]: string; }'.
Property '"latitude"' is incompatible with index signature.
Type '{ alias: "latitude"; required: false; }' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

I checked the ng-maps [dependency list](https://ng-maps.github.io/core/dependencies.html) and I have everything they listed, as well as @types/googlemaps, which is mentioned [here](https://ng-maps.github.io/core/index.html). I've tried it with the newer @types/google.maps, and get what look like the same errors. Here's a partial list from package.json:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.0",
    "@ng-maps/core": "^5.0.3",
    "@ng-maps/google": "^5.0.4",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/googlemaps": "^3.43.3",
  }
```

These all seem in line with the ng-maps dependencies page. Can anyone shed some light on this?